# How does sched_yield() work between two pthreads?

Tags: pthreads, scheduler, producer-consumer

I'm new to this concept and was a bit confused. Let's say I want to run two pthreads on a single core. If I call `sched_yield()` from one pthread, doesn't it halt itself and relinquish the CPU to the other pthread until that other pthread calls `sched_yield()`? I'm trying to work this out with two pthreads sharing an array where pthread2 reads off elements inserted by pthread1. There are instances where my code may start running from pthread2, but the array is empty, and I need it to halt via `sched_yield()` and let pthread1 fill in the array. However, pthread1 doesn't seem to kick in and fill in the array and I'm not sure why. Can I really just call `sched_yield()` to switch into pthread1 and stop pthread2 from running until pthread1 calls `sched_yield()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using conditional variables. Have a look at [pthread_cond_init()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_init), [pthread_cond_wait()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait), [pthread_cond_signal()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal)...
You are implementing a so-called "producer/consumer problem" : multiple producer threads write into a shared resource and multiple consumer threads read from it. A synchronization is needed to make sure that:

- A consumer will read consistent data each time it accesses the resource. Multiple readers can read at the same time as they don't modify the resource;
- No consumer can access the resource if a producer is modifying it and conversely no writer can access the resource if at least one reader is reading it;
- A producer must have an exclusive access to the resource to write on it without interleaving with other producers.

Here is an example program which implements several threads writing/reading a global shared resource. A producer and a consumer function respectively receive a callback to write and read the global resource. They both use a condition variable to maintain a counter of readers to make possible multiple readers read the resource at the same time and make sure that only one writer modify the resource at any moment when there are no pending readers. To simplify the source file, the return codes of the services are not checked.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
typedef int (* write_op_t)(void *data);
typedef int (* read_op_t)(void *data);
int readers;

char resource[50];

int producer(write_op_t wr, void *data)
{
  int rc;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  // If there are readers ==> we wait
  while (readers > 0) {
    // Wait for a signal from the readers
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
  }

  // The mutex is locked here

  // Write operation
  rc = (* wr)(data);

  // wake up any waiting writer
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  return rc;
}


int consumer(read_op_t rd, void *data)
{
  int rc;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  // One more reader
  readers ++;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  // Read operation
  rc = (* rd)(data);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  // One less reader
  readers --;

  // Wake up any waiting writer
  if (readers == 0) {
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
  }

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}


int read_op(void *data)
{
  char *name = (char *)data;
  char local_resource[sizeof(resource) + 50];

  snprintf(local_resource, sizeof(local_resource), "readers=%d, resource='%s'", readers, resource);
  printf("%s: %s\n", name, local_resource);

  return 0;
}

int write_op(void *data)
{
  char *name = (char *)data;
  printf("%s writing\n", name);
  snprintf(resource, sizeof(resource), "%s", name);

  return 0;
}


void *entry(void *p)
{
  char *name = (char *)p;
  int i = 10;
  int rc;

  do {

    if (i & 0x1) {
      rc = producer(write_op, name);
    } else {
      rc = consumer(read_op, name);
    }

    i --;

  } while (i);

  printf("End of %s\n", name);

  return NULL;

}


int main(void)
{
  pthread_t tid[4];
  int i;
  char *name[4];

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
    name[i] = malloc(20);
    snprintf(name[i], 20, "thread#%d", i);
    pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, entry, name[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    free(name[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Under Linux, it is built like this:

```
$ gcc prod_cons.c -o prod_cons -lpthread
```

Then, you can run it

```
$ ./prod_cons
thread#0: readers=1, resource=''
thread#1: readers=2, resource=''
thread#2: readers=2, resource=''
thread#3: readers=2, resource=''
thread#3 writing
thread#2 writing
thread#1 writing
thread#1: readers=1, resource='thread#1'
thread#1 writing
thread#1: readers=1, resource='thread#1'
thread#3: readers=1, resource='thread#1'
thread#1 writing
thread#0 writing
thread#0: readers=1, resource='thread#0'
thread#2: readers=1, resource='thread#0'
thread#1: readers=2, resource='thread#0'
thread#1 writing
thread#3 writing
thread#3: readers=1, resource='thread#3'
thread#2 writing
thread#2: readers=1, resource='thread#2'
thread#0 writing
thread#0: readers=1, resource='thread#0'
thread#0 writing
thread#0: readers=1, resource='thread#0'
thread#1: readers=1, resource='thread#0'
thread#2 writing
thread#0 writing
thread#0: readers=1, resource='thread#0'
thread#0 writing
End of thread#0
thread#1 writing
End of thread#1
thread#3 writing
thread#3: readers=1, resource='thread#3'
thread#2: readers=2, resource='thread#3'
thread#2 writing
thread#2: readers=1, resource='thread#2'
thread#2 writing
End of thread#2
thread#3 writing
thread#3: readers=1, resource='thread#3'
thread#3 writing
End of thread#3
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer was very detailed and it provides a lot of the concepts I need to get my code working. It makes a lot more sense to me now.

Answer (score 1):

When a thread is calling pthread_yield(), the system just enters the scheduler. Then, the scheduler decides what thread must execute, according to many criteria related to the operating system (type of scheduling, priorités, current CPU load number of processors, etc.).
In short you should not use pthread_yield() to synchronize 2 threads that share data but mutexes: Have a look at POSIX API like pthread_mutex_lock().

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The mutex seems to be crucial for this to work.